Sublime Simple FTP Deploy suddenly stopped working on save
I have Simple ftp deploy plugin set up. It was working for several years with no issue, yet today I opened sublime, tried to edit some code and save - nothing is happening. Console is empty.
All the config files are still in the same place from when it was working.
I tried to reinstall the package and writing setting file from scratch - that didn't help.
Any ideas what this might be and how to fix this?
btw im using latest macos. Thank you.
